# Jquery Widget vs Jquery Plugin, Differences, When to use which?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-widgets

What are the main differences between a Jquery Widget and a Jquery Plugin.

Mainly:

- What purposes do they serve
- Is one better than another or do they both have their place in the jquery world
- What is an example where I would want to use one over another
- What is an example if any where either would be a fine solution
- What is an example of a widely used widget and a widely used plugin

Comment: From Googling, it appears like "widgets" are something you use in conjunction with jQuery UI and plugins are used with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard of a jQuery widget. I imagine some people might use the term to describe a... widget... that has been made with jQuery. Certainly there are widgets in jQuery UI, for example. It's an odd question.

A widget is a widget (always includes a visual element, sometimes includes reusable functionality), and can be a subset of a plugin or a plugin in and of itself.

A plugin extends jQuery directly and may or may not have a visual component.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between jQuery Widget and plugin is state.

please see details on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62813110/details-difference-between-jquery-plugin-and-widget)